# What is the antiderivative of $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3 = C$$

How would one solve this? I tried integrating both sides and I got:

$$y + \int\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3\;dx = Cx + D$$

What is $$\int\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3\;dx ?$$

Thank you for the help =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not require the second derivative to exist:

Note, that with $u(x)=y'(x)$, you get the equation $u(x)+(u(x))^3=C$ from which you can conclude that $u(x)$ is a constant, say $D$. But then $y(x)=\int u(x)\,dx=Dx+E$, where $E$ is another constant.

Now you can insert $y'(x)=D$ into your differential equation to find the constant $D$, $D+D^3=C$ (the general solutions (there are three of them, one is real) do not look too nice). The constant $E$ cannot be determined with the information you have.

Comment: Thank you, I have some boundary conditions in my problem, so I can use them to solve the constants =)

Answer (score 2):

Hint
$$(y'+(y')^3)'=0\Longrightarrow y''+3y'^2y''=0$$
$$y''(1+3y'^2)=0$$
so
$y''=0,$ or $3y'^2=-1$
then it is easy to find it

Comment: Thank you for the assist =)